# How to see the values stored in a sql table through Sql SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, groovy

how can i query the values stored in a database table ?
i have tried the following code.

```
sql.execute("select top 5 MachineName from [MACHINES]")
logger.info "MachineName is: '{$MachineName}'
```

I am trying to query the TOP 5 values from the table and display in my logger. In my code logger.info is equal to the printin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the very top of ANY groovy sql documentation:

```
sql.eachRow('select top 5 MachineName from [MACHINES]') { row ->
  logger.info "MachineName is: '{${row[0]}}'
}
```

further reading http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html#_reading_rows

UPD:

To make a map of results:

```
def map = [:]
sql.eachRow('select top 5 MachineName, order from [MACHINES]') { row ->
  map[ row[ 0 ] ] = row[ 1 ]
}
logger.log "my map -> $map"
```

Comment: I tired to run with the above syntax i get the following error.---- Groovy:[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#getAt(int). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.

Comment: try simply `${row}` and see what would come out

Comment: Yes it works. I can fetch the top 5 machineName. How can i assign in an array. like before you suggested for example row[0] = Machine 12, row[1] = Machine 6..... In further i am trying to assign into order[0]=row[0], so i can call anytime!